# ffmpeg re-streaming to another RTMP

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I stop my ffmpeg re-stream from crashing? I'm running the following command in a .BAT file:

```
:loop
ffmpeg -i "RTMP://IPADDRESS:1935/LIVE/STREAMNAME.STREAM pageUrl=http://URL.COM swfurl=http://domain.com/licensed/player-licensed.swf live=1" -isync  -vcodec copy -b:v 400k -acodec copy -b:a 128000 -ar 32000 -f flv "rtmp://IP:1935/LIVE/CHANNELNAME"
goto loop
```

Is there anything wrong with this line of code other than than the links I put for demonstration purposes?

It keeps crashing – something about DTS codec. Maybe I should use something other than "copy" for audio codecs?

Comment: It does not make sense to try to copy a stream *and* setting its sample and bit rate. Can you leave out the `-acodec copy`? What is the full error log? Please always include this.

Comment: Hi
If I leave out acodec copy it throws an error.

Comment: What error would that be? Again, please show the error log – we cannot guess what the problem is without seeing `ffmpeg`'s full, uncut console log.

Comment: Can we text chat on skype or something?
Thanks

Comment: I don't have persistent Internet connection at the moment, sorry. Also, for the benefit of future visitors it'd be better to try and solve the issue here – there are some other FFmpeg experts who might have an idea what's going on!

Comment: where can i find the error log?

Comment: Please just copy everything your `ffmpeg` script outputs and paste it here. Thanks!

Comment: http://s22.postimg.org/fuemj2vkh/error5.png this is one of the errors

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

until ffmpeg -i http://serverIP:host/user/pass/stream -c:v libx264 -preset medium -maxrate 3500k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://serverIP:port/live/name;do

echo "restarting ffmpeg command"
sleep 1
done
```

Write a bash script that will restart the ffmpeg instruction. Run `nohup ./batch-file.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Comment: The asker appears to be using Windows (they mention a batch file), so this won't work unless they have WSL or Bash on Windows installed.